# How to connect / stitch multiple edges?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, edges, sculpt

In some parts of this mesh, especially on the corners and edges, there are edges that aren't connected. I only discovered it when I tried to sculpt, and this "hole" appeared.

[image: hole in a corner of the mesh]

When I went to Edit mode, it turned out that the edges on this corner part of the mesh are "duplicated".[image: duplicated edges]

You can clearly see it here:[image]

Now, I know that I can fix this manually, and it's not a huge problem here, where I have to deal with just several of these edges. But I want to know if there's any automatic method to connect them, in case I find a spot with thousands of them, or if I already start sculpting and want to fix this after. Mind you, "Merge vertices" or "Merge edges" doesn't work automatically here, because I still need to select and merge each pair of vertices/edges individually. Is there an option, either in Edit mode or Sculpt mode, to kind of "stitch" these kinds of holes? Or better yet, first locate and then stitch them automatically?

Comment: you can try Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold and fill the hole, or select all, then Mesh > Clean Up > Fill Holes (and increase the Sides value in the Operator box. If it doesn't work you can boolean these parts with another object

Comment: Thank you very much @moonboots, the first two methods worked perfectly! I mean almost, after these steps there's still an ugly 0-area face in edit mode, but as soon as I start sculpting with dyntopo, it disappears. So that solves my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try *Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold* and fill the hole, or select all, then *Mesh > Clean Up > Fill Holes* (and increase the *Sides* value in the *Operator* box). If it doesn't work you can boolean these parts with another object.